# Applying the CLT to the exponentially distributed waiting times of a Markov process

Tags: statistics, markov-process, central-limit-theorem

Suppose I have a Markov process $X_t$ with exponentially distributed waiting times $T_i$ between the jumps, then with $\tau_k = \sum_{i=1}^k T_i$ one can describe the time until the $k$-th jump.
Since $T_i\sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$, I know that $\mathbb{E}(\tau_k)=\frac{k}{\lambda}$ and Var$(\tau_k)=\frac{k}{\lambda^2}$.

Now I asked myself if it was possible to apply the CLT to the $\tau_k$, if the $T_i$ are independent?

For me it seems like it should be possible, but I don't know if it makes any difference, that the $\tau_k$ are part of a Markov process?

Comment: Yes it is possible (though I think the iid timing of jumps is a Poisson process).  $\tau_k$ actually has a gamma distribution with shape parameter $k$, but with the usual relocation and rescaling has a distribution which converges on a normal distribution as $k$ increases.  If the $\lambda$ parameter varies with $i$ then it gets more complicated

Comment: @Henry Thank you! Tbh I have never heard of the gamma distribution before, so thats great to know! So this means that the distribution function of $Z_k=\frac{\tau_k-k/\lambda }{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}$ converges pointwise to the distribution function of the normal distribution for $k\to\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes - just like that - you have the sum of $k$ iid distributions with finite variance, so the CLT applies.